# Symfony3 Attempted to call an undefined method named "getId" of class "AppBundle\Entity\CustomerOnline"

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I'm new at symfony and I'm trying to start an application with it.

I've created the following doctrine orm definition in 
/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/CustomerOnline.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\CustomerOnline:
type: entity
table: customer_online
uniqueConstraints:
    customer_online_tracking_uindex:
        columns:
            - tracking
id:
    tracking:
        type: string
        nullable: false
        length: 15
        options:
            fixed: false
        id: true
fields:
    recipientPhone:
        type: string
        nullable: true
        length: 15
        options:
            fixed: false
        column: recipient_phone
repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\CustomerOnlineRepository
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

and then I used the doctrine:generate:entities command to create my entity

I also used the doctrine:generate:crud command to generate a crud controller for my entity

When I navigate to the route to add an instance of my Entity to the DB it saves the data correctly however when it redirects to show the instance at /customeronline/1111111111/show I get an error

```
 Attempted to call an undefined method named "getId" of class "AppBundle\Entity\CustomerOnline".
500 Internal Server Error - UndefinedMethodException
```

In the controller I see that it has generated the following code for the newAction

```
/**
     * Creates a new CustomerOnline entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $customerOnline = new CustomerOnline();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\CustomerOnlineType', $customerOnline);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($customerOnline);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('customeronline_show', array('id' => $customerOnline->getId()));
        }

        return $this->render('customeronline/new.html.twig', array(
            'customerOnline' => $customerOnline,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

But in the CustomerOnline Entity it doesn't have the getId() or setId() function but instead correctly the getTracking() and setTracking($tracking) since I defined my id field to tracking in the CustomerOnline.orm.yml file

My question is why is the generator putting the getId() function in the controller instead of the getTracking() one since `tracking` is the name of my id in the orm.yml definition and how can I change it to default to that one?

The twig template responsible for generating that code was originally as  here

```
/**
{% block phpdoc_method_header %}
 * Creates a new {{ entity }} entity.
{% endblock phpdoc_method_header %}
 *
{% block phpdoc_method_annotations %}
{% if 'annotation' == format %}
 * @Route("/new", name="{{ route_name_prefix }}_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
{% endif %}
{% endblock phpdoc_method_annotations %}
 */
{% block method_definition %}
public function newAction(Request $request)
 {% endblock method_definition %}
{
 {% block method_body %}
    ${{ entity_singularized }} = new {{ entity_class }}();
    $form = $this->createForm('{{ namespace }}\Form\{{ entity_class }}Type', ${{ entity_singularized }});
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist(${{ entity_singularized }});
        $em->flush();

        {% if 'show' in actions -%}
            return $this->redirectToRoute('{{ route_name_prefix }}_show', array('id' => ${{ entity_class|lower }}->getId()));
        {%- else -%}
            return $this->redirectToRoute('{{ route_name_prefix }}_index'));
        {%- endif %}

    }
{% endblock method_body %}

{% block method_return %}
    return $this->render('{{ entity|lower|replace({'\\': '/'}) }}/new.html.twig', array(
        '{{ entity_singularized }}' => ${{ entity_singularized }},
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
 {% endblock method_return %}
}
```

The only change I did was from

```
 $this->redirectToRoute('{{ route_name_prefix }}_show', array('id' => ${{ entity_class|lower }}->getId()));
```

to

```
 return $this->redirectToRoute('{{ route_name_prefix }}_show', array('id' => ${{ entity_singularized }}->getId()));
```

because the variable name was wrong in lower case and the system said it wasn't defined

Comment: As far as I know, symfony CRUD by command line work for entities generated throught command line too. And you need to define these entities as class, with annotation. [Check this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html#doctrine-mapping-information)

Comment: I see, however it's stated that every type, annotation,yml, xml are the same to do the same things even though it's best practice to use annotations so I don't think this is the problem. I actually tried with annotation and had the same issue. As far as the CRUD by command line is concerned I thought it could also be used to quickly import an entire database with doctrine:mapping:import and then doctrine:generate:entities

Comment: Getting the same throught entities class & annotations isn't normal, but about your way, never tested before. Else, your error come from the fact you didn't get your getter/setter. But again, I apologize, no ideas how it work with yml class definition

Comment: It's fine I really appreciate any advice to working this out. What I meant with same behaviour is that if my classes do not use the automatically generated id named as `id`  but with another name `e.g. tracking` they just cause the error that getId() is missing. I can obviously go in the class and for my case create the functions getId() & setId($id)  which just call the getTracking() and setTracking($tracking) functions and everything works properly. The issue is that the generator won't read which variable name is actually set as the id in the class whether it's annotation or yml or xml